# How to integrate iContact in Android Application?

Tags: android

I need new user subscription via iContact in my Android application.
Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see iContact's documentation on this here:

http://developer.icontact.com/documentation/subscriptions/